# One word to replace "takes as input"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking to replace the phrase "takes as input" to make a sentence flow better but I can't think of the right word to use. I want to say "the simulator ______ a spatial map and an algorithm".

Comment: The sentence flows perfectly fine with “takes as input” or “takes … as input. As far as I know, there’s no single-word equivalent that would make the sentence flow better.

Comment: I might use "accepts" or "inputs".

Comment: I think I'll stick with "takes as input". "Accepts" seems like it would work as well though. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Rather then "process" or variant, I'd recommend **accepts**. Then map and algorithm are implicitly identified as inputs. Technically, you would be clearest by saying "accepts as inputs", but the meaning is clear in context.

Comment: Although I've posted my own "cheat" answer, I have voted for this as the best one-word answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about 'registers'?

"The simulator **registers** a spatial map and an algorithm."

As per Google,
Register :
1) *of an instrument) detect and show (a reading) automatically*.
2) *enter or record on an official list or directory*.

So, I'd recommend the usage of the aforementioned, if besides accepting, the simulator recognizes the objects as well.

Answer (score 0):

The poster has the following problem:

> “I’m looking to replace the phrase **“takes as input”** to make a sentence flow better…”

He supposes that the solution will be a one-word answer and asks explicitly for such in an example sentence. I feel that — as often in trying to improve technical writing — he has trapped himself into thinking that one particular type of structure must be the answer to his problem. I shall suggest an answer in other terms. Some may think this is ‘cheating’ — not answering the specific question. I think my answer is more generally useful in its approach.

Like others, I do not find the original so bad, but compliment the poster on wishing to replace a three-word noun construction with a single verb. Unfortunately, I think that the noun, “input” is technically difficult to replace without changing the meaning slightly. Thus, the single-word answer I prefer, “accepts” (from @WhatRoughBeast) is not exclusive. (“This shop accepts Euros” does not exclude the fact that it accepts Pounds Sterling.)

My solution is to keep “input” and use it with the clearest and simplest verb, “to be”, changing the structure a little:

> The **input** for the simulator **is** a spatial map and an algorithm.

The meaning is almost exactly the same as the original.

Answer (score -1):

If you must use one word,  "processes" is an option, but you don't say, and I don't see, what is particularly wrong with 'takes as input'.

Answer (score -1):

I think processes is your best bet, but depending on what the input is, *parses* may also work.

> **parse**
>
> 2. Computers (of a compiler) to read (program code) so as to produce a correct output.
> 3. to analyse (data).